# Why do i get an error that says: "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"?

Tags: python-3.x

```
    from random import randint

    secret_num=randint(1,100)
    num_guesses=0
    guess = 0

     for num_guesses in range(5):
            guess=eval(input('Enter your guess (1-100): '))
            if guess < secret_num:
                    print('HIGHER.', 5-num_guesses, 'guesses left.\n')
            elif guess > secret_num:
                  print('LOWER', 5-num_guesses, 'guesses left.\n')
          else:
                    print('You got it!')
                    break
   else:
           print('You lose. The correct number is', secret_num)
```

What seems to be the problem with this piece of code? Whenever I run it, it gives this error message:  File "guessing_game2.py", line 11
if guess < secret_num:
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

What should I do to correct this?

Comment: It won't be reproducible from what you've pasted in the textbox, but it's likely that in your code you're using tabs to indent some lines, and spaces to indent other lines. This is not allowed - it has to be all one or the other. You can google ways to have your IDE auto-indent your code, or do it yourself (and I recommend you configure your IDE to automatically replace tabs with an equivalent number of spaces when you press the tab button, to avoid this issue)

Comment: The `else` is not in the right indentation

Comment: You are mixing up spaces and tab characters to indent your code. Convert all tabs to the proper amount of spaces.

Comment: It means literally what it says. You're using both tabs and spaces for indentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually i was able to indent it using 4 spaces (almost) and now it runs just fine. I was using the nano editor. I saw another post with a similar issue and they didn't recommend tabs, instead they recommended spaces.